# Magento 1.7: Unable to incorporate joinField in product collection

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm having a problem where I can't get add `joinField()` to a product collection.. I have no clue why it doesn't work because it should be really simple or throw some errors at least. Needless to say, it is driving me nuts. I'm interested in looking at products and the total dollar amount in sales from them. This is what I have from a book called "Magento PHP Developer's Guide" and the [Magento Wiki](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento).

```
public function getProducts($categoryId) { 

$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId)
    ->getProductCollection()
    ->joinField('o', 'sales_flat_order_item', array('o.row_total', 'o.product_id'), 'main_table.entity_id = o.product_id');
}

// die; when uncommented, this function WILL NOT die here

return $productCollection;
}
```

I'm getting the `->joinField()` method right out of the book, but it doesn't grab any product. Strangely, the function doesn't even return anything because when the `die` line is uncommented, the function does not terminate there. Instead, the front-end will simply just skip this function without throwing any errors (that I can see at this time) and just doesn't display any blocks using this function. What am I missing here?

It works when I remove `joinField()` like below.

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryIds)
    ->getProductCollection();
```

UPDATE:

Further testing show that the following works. Note that if I use `main_table` instead of `e`, it does **not** work. If I look at the query generated from this, `main_table` is not replaced by the main table; instead, query contains the literal string "main_table".

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryIds)
    ->getSelect()
    ->join(array('o' => 'sales_flat_order_item'),
        'e.entity_id = o.product_id',
        'o.row_total'
    );
```

While this doesn't.

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryIds)
    ->joinTable(
        array('o' => 'sales_flat_order_item'),
       'e.entity_id = o.product_id',
       'o.row_total'
    );
```

Maybe I don't see some simple mistake.. but I just don't see what's wrong.

Comment: You have a syntax error: `}` should be after `return ...;`

Comment: Table aliases aren't supposed to be replaced - so that's ok. I forgot when you join tables using the resource model directly the main table may be aliased as e.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getProducts($categoryId) { 
    $productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId)
        ->getProductCollection()
        ->joinTable( // JoinTable makes more sense.
           array('o' => 'sales/order_item'),
           'main_table.entity_id = o.product_id'
           array('row_total'),
        )
    ;

    return $productCollection;
}
```

It will probably return all fields in the `catalog_product_entity` table PLUS the `row_total` from the `sales_order_item` table. You might be able to use `addAttributeToSelect('o.product_id')` right before the join, just to clear the unwanted fields.

Comment: Same problem persists, though. Once `->joinTable()` is added, the function does not work. It does not throw any errors and somehow Magento skips it and renders the rest of the page on the front-end. Even if I put `die` right after `return` in your code, it will not end there. I can't even print the query with `printlogquery`. And I did notice the missing comma after the 2nd arg. so it's not a syntax problem.

Comment: I managed to get `join()` work instead of `joinTable()`. I updated my post. Could you take a look and see there' anything wrong?

Comment: Return ends the execution. A `die` function after it wouldn't do anything.